# Creating a batch file to launch the currently opened applications and folders

Tags: windows, shell, script, shortcuts

Example: If I were viewing example.txt in a Notepad and editing an image in GIMP, I'd like to generate a batch file that would launch those files using those applications after I've closed  the windows. Is there a way to create a launcher like this without manually copying and pasting the names of open files and applications into a batch file or shell script?

Comment: Could you please clarify... If they are open already, why would you need a launcher for them?

Comment: So you could open that set of files in those apps in future, just by running the batch file?

Comment: I want to generate a launcher for all the open windows so that I can quickly launch all the windows again after closing them.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958123/powershell-script-to-check-application-thats-locking-a-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, if you use PowerShell etc.

Use

```
get-process | select name
```

this will get a list of process names

Now you can find the commandline for the process names you interested in with the following

```
gwmi win32_process -filter "name=$processname'" | select commandLine
```

Now you can [use PowerShell to create shortcuts](http://powershell-tips.blogspot.com/2011/03/create-shortcut-with-powershell.html)

You can create a simple script do what you want, as there are other things you may want to add for the shortcuts other than the commandline (which is your target in the shortcut) and process name.

Comment: I like when responses start with "Yes, you can." :)